# STFT Time Variance - Threshold

Tags: signal-analysis, stft

This is a follow up question to: [Segment/Idenfication of signal from a spectrogram](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14070/segment-idenfication-of-signal-from-a-spectrogram)

My main goal is to identify (segment) all of the calls from a given signal. The signal looks like the following (Spectrogram):
[image]

Notice how there are 4 calls within this signal, I would like to identify there are 4 calls and just capture these calls so I can then use this for later analysis.

So far I have carried out the following:

- Computed an STFT (Spectrogram on the time-signal) of a series of bat calls.

The spectrogram shows where each of the calls are, by the high energy levels.

What I am now calculating is the time variance between all of the different calls using the following formula:

$$
T =  \sum_a^b x \sqrt{re*re+im*im}
$$

This is calculated for each of the bins, the result is as follows:

[image]

Where I belive the `x axis` relates to the time, and the `y axis is the total variance`

From this, it is clear where the most significant parts of the signal are, the 4 spikes indicate the parts that I need to extract, it's just how... I suppose I could use a threshold value, and state that:

```
if variance > THRESHOLD:
   keep the block 
else:
   place "0" in each of the elements
```

But, how would I calculate the threshold in order to the above? What if the next set of calls are different to the threshold set for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

By doing the following (above) and, using a threshold value, I get the following result:

[image]

Therefore, can I calculate each of the frequencies (of the bird calls) based upon this? I.e. $$(binnumber * Fs) / NFFT$$

Where `Fs` is the frequency sample rate and NFFT is the size of each of the bins?

Comment: @down-voter - Why has this question been downvoted? :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a factor $0<c<1$ of the average of the variances

$\mathrm{THRESHOLD}=c\cdot{\operatorname{avg}(\operatorname{var}(X))}$

Since the ,,calls'' (I suppose you're referring to birds) start sharply but fade out gradually, you could extend every period a little in the front and a little more in the end.

Comment: Hello, please see my updated post! =) thanks for the reply, though! It worked, kind of!

Comment: I would have expected that you use a lower c to cover more of the signal. But anyways, you should be able to find the peak value. The spectrogram however shows rather broadband signals, so I would not expect the result to be very clear.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `lower c` what would the `c` value be in this case? Either way, the values seem pretty clear. On every signal I have tested with; the algorithm is working fine.. Just need to calculate the correct threshold value now

Comment: @user1326876 - Also, is it possible to plot the frequencies related to the bins? (the way I described in my edit)

Comment: I just noticed I was talking about $\mathrm{THRESHOLD}=(1-c)\cdot\mathrm{min}(\mathrm{var}(X))+c\cdot \mathrm{max}(\mathrm{var}(X))$. Either way, $c$ is just a weight. Bin index is proportional to frequency, yes.

Comment: thanks so c can even be anything or does it have to be a specific value? Ok I think once I get the threshold done my project is done (: